# DKIM fails for Gmail only. Emails in spam

Tags: email, gmail, dkim

I've been banging my head at this for 2 days. I've installed a fresh copy of [Virtualmin](https://virtualmin.com) and I enabled DKIM as mentioned in the documentation. Everything went fine. I've added spf and dkim records in my dns as well which were generated by virtualmin

```
v=spf1 a mx a:rohtakvivah.com ip4:172.104.159.124 ip6:2a01:7e01::f03c:91ff:fed4:bdcc ?all

v=DKIM1; k=rsa; t=s; p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDSINQFbPLkzZ5e0eMpBArxWMQRslJC7nmTBqNOsK+L97nj2C8He8T+PgQYObhf7p8H/O3IHAYVc7GXCgFjzuxx86ncWfxgO4X5L6FZwUC4awl0XcI4zqcUtO3+SlXzo5/6NVRY+Kt83c+4yUYYwymvsovZ+mBoS0/h64zyFTQg0QIDAQAB;
```

I've changed DKIM configuration's cononicalization from "simple" tp "relaxed/relaxed" in `/etc/opendkim.conf`
I'm sending mails via usermail and they are ending up in gmail's spam because they are failing dkim. Here's the report:

```
Delivered-To: vipul@bwdmedia.net
Received: by 10.100.166.5 with SMTP id l5csp395785pje;
        Fri, 18 Aug 2017 00:08:05 -0700 (PDT)
X-Received: by 10.223.198.9 with SMTP id n9mr4614607wrg.185.1503040085657;
        Fri, 18 Aug 2017 00:08:05 -0700 (PDT)
ARC-Seal: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; t=1503040085; cv=none;
        d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        b=Mly2S2Fl1SiJUTalp2HJPCaNIwaiYrHY7LARLeEM+I71znYdacNg8w/9oKVZbVgPra
         3axnAIC56db6C2wBmgzFXhTexSQ7CCkGD6It2m3gnkqjTzzrXIcyiNKzQav8lpdkllNN
         h4qZ0wFWEFr8v/Za/uif1NxL0N3lxReHeyPbuQodRmXunFrZEXXAzwLHHmYQu6Lue7o/
         dIX1zF4v6zgvjOma3aw3LKon9cEJO5UHIONpqpFPOCCCwSYc8+tkx5+zcA8AJnBOGbC7
         Uql+mFjnS6GVw0MPW2bMydWpDzVLsqhSmlTIR2EOJ0zt0+L5aB5OhLf+v43yvkR6Vx5z
         YwRg==
ARC-Message-Signature: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        h=date:message-id:to:subject:from:dkim-signature
         :arc-authentication-results;
        bh=47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU=;
        b=bu8aTh0lxBLmP2p4uGZpwITiGJS7ZgoLsvuRUC99wkKJad4dR8fmThCh641Y+rTBEJ
         5/rg+1mig1y3GAMzgVH/Fd10+YvhKwT+g+g69Z4vxhz9FnPJG3AK0vsI7/Ce4rrvX15T
         Eo2S6DgWW2hA37yYgBmxECAWJ8NLmXL2bCvRZ5Y/YE7V6GqEGxpXt3WXzKwYuC2aLMvH
         q8SYhl0BYVhym4ttVOifrhcRv97q4wjSXDr2X/iTDE6b5FXwxVAcaF83x8nbV43xYlBA
         oN6TerJB+agBS++YvEjUOYZKLaoFf6M8J3pHZJoxMlThctSnisBGsAoWBNQM/S02lNWK
         Ybdg==
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
       dkim=fail header.i=@rohtakvivah.com header.s=2017 header.b=SP0BiHsl;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of rohtakvivah@rohtakvivah.com designates 172.104.159.124 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=rohtakvivah@rohtakvivah.com
Return-Path: <rohtakvivah@rohtakvivah.com>
Received: from ubun1-frank.rohtakvivah.com (rohtakvivah.com. [172.104.159.124])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id r14si3790302wrc.496.2017.08.18.00.08.05
        for <vipul@bwdmedia.net>
        (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Fri, 18 Aug 2017 00:08:05 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of rohtakvivah@rohtakvivah.com designates 172.104.159.124 as permitted sender) client-ip=172.104.159.124;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       dkim=fail header.i=@rohtakvivah.com header.s=2017 header.b=SP0BiHsl;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of rohtakvivah@rohtakvivah.com designates 172.104.159.124 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=rohtakvivah@rohtakvivah.com
Received: from ubun1-frank.rohtakvivah.com (localhost [127.0.0.1]) by ubun1-frank.rohtakvivah.com (Postfix) with SMTP id 039CC7AFE6 for <vipul@bwdmedia.net>; Fri, 18 Aug 2017 12:38:05 +0530 (IST)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/simple; d=rohtakvivah.com; s=2017; t=1503040085; bh=frcCV1k9oG9oKj3dpUqdJg1PxRT2RSN/XKdLCPjaYaY=; h=From:Subject:To:Date:From; b=SP0BiHsl1g07iOHwTKYPa3cpyXDhFeYYQ6SvNdEOnyMGX4tW78RiFwfnvx3ev0bMu
     f2o+EdHWRRaJsdlsueBxIU5/v5jgsK31gk/BENgFiWhPvzDluPfEB/4yGJL9JSbFJf
     Jp7SUDmWNSa3qkLjMGjHDsUlHz6rkdTZSCGQe5e8=
From: Rohtak Vivah <rohtakvivah@rohtakvivah.com>
Subject: test 16
To: vipul@bwdmedia.net
Message-Id: <1503040084.8019@rohtakvivah.com>
X-Mailer: Usermin 1.710
Date: Fri, 18 Aug 2017 12:38:04 +0530 (IST)
Content-Type: text/plain
```

I've checked every spf and dkim checker site and they all report both records as present and valid. I don' t know whats happening here. Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: I got so tired of solving different errors with DKIM one day I just removed DKIM from all my domains and swore not to touch it again. I havnt had one email fail delivery since lol. Must be well over a year now.

Answer (score 1):

Had same problem.

helped this post: https://www.hmailserver.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=27904

> Changing BOTH 'Header Method' and 'Body Method' to the default
>   'relaxed' instantly made my DKIM signatures acceptable to gMail.
>   Thanks for posting back your solution.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks!